# GenerateResource task is not creating resources file

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have written a task for generating resource as below inside .csproj file. But the .resources and .resurces.dll files are not generated. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<ItemGroup>    
    <Compile Include="$(GeneratedFilesOutputFolder)\MessageInfo.cs" Condition="Exists('$(GeneratedFilesOutputFolder)\MessageInfo.cs')" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="$(GeneratedFilesOutputFolder)\MessageInfo.resx" LogicalName="MessageInfo.resources"/>
</ItemGroup>    
<Target Name = "GenerateResources">
    <GenerateResource
       Sources="$(GeneratedFilesOutputFolder)\MessageInfo.resx"
       OutputResources="$(GeneratedFilesOutputFolder)\MessageInfo.resources">
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputResources"
            ItemName="MessageInfoResource"/>
        <Output TaskParameter = "FilesWritten" ItemName = "FileWrites"/>
    </GenerateResource>
</Target>   
<Target Name="GenerateSatelliteAssemblies"
        Inputs="@(MessageInfoResource)"
    Outputs="$(BuildPath)\MessageInfo.resources.dll" >
    <AL             
        EmbedResources = "@(MessageInfoResource)"
        ToolExe="$(AlToolExe)"
        ToolPath="$(AlToolPath)"
        OutputAssembly = "$(BuildPath)\MessageInfo.resources.dll" >
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputAssembly" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </AL>
    <CreateItem
        Include = "$(BuildPath)\MessageInfo.resources.dll"          >
        <Output TaskParameter = "Include" ItemName = "SatelliteAssemblies" />
    </CreateItem>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, potential culprits include `Exists('$(GeneratedFilesOutputFolder)\MessageInfo.cs')` not evaluating to `True`, the target hooks you are using not being triggered as you expect or your targets being replaced by empty targets due to the relevant `.targets` file(s) importing after your targets are evaluated. The best way to check these things is to add `-bl` to your `dotnet build` or `msbuild` command, install [MSBuild Structured/Binary Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) and use it to open the `msbuild.binlog` file in the directory containing the project or solution you are building. This will allow you to inspect the targets that result after your .csproj and all imports are evaluated, the result of your item conditional, whether the target call hierarchy includes your targets the way you expect and whether any relevant targets are skipped due to `Inputs` and `Outputs` attributes.